# Importing SQL Server SQL_VARIANT data type to OrientDB vertex - which property type should I use?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-etl, sql-variant

I am evaluating OrientDB as a replacement for MS SQL Server.  One of the SQL Server tables I need to import into OrientDB contains time-series data with the value column using a SQL_VARIANT data type.  I'm struggling to identify the best data type to use for the equivalent property in a new OrientDB vertex.  I'm hesitant to convert it a STRING, but I don't see an equivalent variant type.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

OrientDB Teleporter is a tool that synchronizes a RDBMS to OrientDB database. You can use Teleporter to:

- Import your existing RDBMS to OrientDB
- Keep your OrientDB database synchronized with changes from the RDBMS. In this case the database on RDBMS remains the primary and the database on OrientDB a synchronized copy. Synchronization is one way, so all the changes in OrientDB database will not be propagated to the RDBMS
  Teleporter is fully compatible with several RDBMS that have a JDBC driver: we successfully tested Teleporter with Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL, PostgreSQL and HyperSQL. Teleporter manages all the necessary type conversions between the different DBMSs and imports all your data as Graph in OrientDB.

**NOTE:** This feature is available both for the OrientDB Enterprise Edition and the OrientDB Community Edition. But beware: in community edition you can migrate your source relational database but you cannot enjoy the synchronize feature, only available in the enterprise edition.

**How Teleporter works**
Teleporter looks for the specific DBMS meta-data in order to perform a logical inference of the source DB schema for the building of a corresponding graph model. Eventually the data importing phase is performed.

Teleporter has a pluggable importing strategy. Two strategies are provided out of the box:

- naive strategy, the simplest one
- naive-aggregate strategy. It performs a "naive" import of the data source. The data source schema is translated semi-directly in a correspondent and coherent graph model using an aggregation policy on the junction tables of dimension equals to 2
  To learn more about the two different execution strategies click here.

For more information: http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/teleporter/Teleporter-Home.html

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how this answers the question.  What is the equivalent data type?